# Commenting gallery items

Tags: 8, comments, media

i want to create a gallery where users can comment on each image. I've seen approaches for Drupal 7, for example:

- Node gallery Module
  This is currently not supported in Drupal 8.
- Gallery / Image Content Type with references
  Is this a suitable approach for more than 1000 pictures?

Is there a better way to make this work in Drupal 8? Am I missing improvements on Drupal 7/8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built 2 gallery type sites with album-image and category-product relations last week - my first 2 Drupal 8 sites! If direct modules are not available, you can try using views to solve your problem by creating your own gallery setup (if acceptable).

**Step 1: Create provision for gallery categories**

Create a taxonomy vocabulary named `gallery_category` and add relevant fields to it. These would serve as albums:

- **image**: album cover
- **body**: album description

**Step 2: Create provision for gallery items**

Create a content-type named `gallery_item` and add relevant fields to it:

- **image**: the image
- **body**: image description
- **category**: reference to the `gallery_category` vocabulary - you can have single or multiple values depending on whether your images would belong to one or more categories (as per requirement).

**Step 3: Set up views**

- Create one view to display a list of all categories
- Create another view or modify the default taxonomy term view to fine-tune the list of gallery items inside a category.
- For the views, if you have too many categories or items, make sure you enable paging or some other relevant solution to make sure all items don't load in a page.

**Note:** This is a general answer to try and help you. Modify the steps and details as necessary to achieve the output you desire. Good luck!